how to override one of the standard open Api responses ? Can i make it?
responses:
    # Если стандартные ответы (см ./responses)
    allOf: 
      - $ref: './responses#'
    200: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<override HERE
      description: OK
      content:

I have external file './responses.yaml'. It has 200, 400, 500 answers and i want to use them but i need to override one of them:
...

200:
  description: OK
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
      ....
201:
  description: OK
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: './common#/producerResponse'

Someone help me ? :)
